# Geospatial quality standards

Tags: data-quality, iso-19110

I am reviewing the geodata quality standards within my organization. During my review I keep coming across the ISO 19100 series. I am wondering if anyone has used these standards and if they have any input on their usefulness. The purpose of my review is as follows:

- identify current organizational standards
- identify potential short comings of my organizations standards
- implement more robust geospatial data quality standard
- implement/develop robust geospatial data quality process(es)
- implement more current metadata and documentation standards

The organization is responsible for maintaining authoritative geospatial data, specifically:

- parcel fabric
- topographic features
- ortho imagery
- stereo imagery

Would anyone recommend venturing into the ISO 19100 standard for such a dataset, or would other standards be more appropriate?

Comment: Are you after a recommendation, or are you after confirmation that the ISO 19100 series of standards (such as 19115 and 19139) are widely used (they are in Europe, see INSPIRE)?

Comment: Good question. I am looking for both. As we are at the beginning of the process we are open to both sides. I would like to hear comments on the usefulness and recommendations, for or against ISO, or even for other options.